# TTGO LoRa32 without OLED display

Tags: esp32, lora

I purchased TTGO Lora Module without OLED display. There is a line of pads in the PCB. When I upload I2C scanner sketch from Arduino IDE, it does not detect any I2C devices.
So, if I want to use a display of my own, e.g. OLED with any kind of I2C controller (SSD1306, SH1106 etc.) it should not collide with any existing controller on-board, is that right?
What about uploading Meshtastic firmware, should it work when I connect i2c display with SSD1306?

Comment: Why not just try it? It's not going to hurt anything if it doesn't work.

Comment: It did not. Hopefully I will find another solution.